# I am trying to add automate the password for this code using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I click run I get a pop out box asking me for username, password, and server. I already put that info on some excel cells but Idk where I can add the password.

```
dataName = (Range("dataName").Value)
passWord = (Range("password").Value)
serverName = (Range("server").Value)
queryName = (Range("Query").Value)

dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;User Id=" & Uname
dbConnectStr1 = "Provider=msdaora;User Id='" & dataName & "'  ;Data Source='" & serverName & "'"

    objmyconn.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr & dbConnectStr1
    objmyconn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
    objmyconn.Open dbConnectStr 'ConnectionString'
    'Declare variables'

'Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Sql = New ADODB.Command
Set ds = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Long
i = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You add it to your connection string as `Pwd=` parameter. Code would look like:

```
dataName = (Range("dataName").Value)
Password = (Range("password").Value)
serverName = (Range("server").Value)
queryName = (Range("Query").Value)

dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;User Id=" & Uname
dbConnectStr1 = "Provider=msdaora;User Id='" & dataName & "'  ;Data Source='" & serverName & "'" & "'  ;Pwd='" & Password & "'"

    objmyconn.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr & dbConnectStr1
    objmyconn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
    objmyconn.Open dbConnectStr 'ConnectionString'
    'Declare variables'

'Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Sql = New ADODB.Command
Set ds = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Long
i = 2
```

Comment: I added it but it still comes out black. ;( @nbaylt

Comment: What do you mean it still comes out black? I just noticed that you are not using `dbConnectStr1` as your connection string. Is there a reason why you detail connection string in 2 different variables? On `objmyconn.Open dbConnectStr` try using `dbConnectStr1` instead.